# Reverse 'buffer' function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, buffer, overlap

MATLAB's buffer function partitions a vector into a matrix where each column is a segment of the vector (time series in my problem). These segments can be overlapping, and the overlap does not need to be 50%.

I was wondering if there is a reverse operation where one would get back a vector after doing some operations on the matrix? I was thinking of a generic solution where the overlap is not 50%.

I have searched the question archive and couldn't find any answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple function I wrote. There is also a simple example commented that you can run and test.

```
function invbuff = invbuffer(X_buff0, noverlap, L)
% Example:
% % % A = (1:40)';
% % % N_over = 2;
% % % N_window = 15;
% % % L = length(A);
% % % Abuff0 = buffer(A, N_window, N_over);
% % % Abuff = Abuff0(:, 1:end-0);
% % % invbuff = invbuffer(Abuff, N_over, L);
invbuff0 = [];
for jj=1:size(X_buff0,2)
vec00 = X_buff0(:,jj);
vec00(1:noverlap) = []; % remove overlapping (or it is zero padding of first frame)
invbuff0 = [invbuff0; vec00];
end
invbuff = invbuff0;
invbuff(L+1:end) = []; % remove zero padding of last frame
% sum(sum([A - invbuff])); % == 0
end
```

Good luck!